Pyspark submit using --py-files .zip
project structure:
project1
|_configs
|_src
|_main
|_com
|_sss
|_app1
|_Jobs
|_models
|_utils
I have zipped the whole project and have init.py under jobs,models,utils.
while doing spark-submit in edge node getting below error.
spark-submit --queue fmoapp-queue --py-files project1.zip main.py
ImportError: No module named src.main.com.sss.app1.utils.DBUtils
Need to know what i am missing here?
Tired Placing the init.py files and tried with
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile() option.

Where is your spark cluster running?

Running in yarn. looks like issue in navigation of folder
